# Nofollow the date/time hyperlink in comment

Tags: comments, links, comment-form, comments-template, comment-meta

Where the date and time of sending each comment is displayed in the comments, it is also a hyperlink.
I want to nofollow this a tag.
I was able to do this through this file in this path:
wp-includes/class-walker-comment.php
Line 448
`'<a href="%s"><time datetime="%s">%s</time></a>',`
converted to:
`'<a rel="nofollow" href="%s"><time datetime="%s">%s</time></a>',`

But this is lost with every WordPress update! I am looking for a way to make this change permanent, like adding a file to the theme (like WooCommerce) or adding a code in the theme function.
Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying core WordPress files, like class-walker-comment.php, is generally not recommended, as your changes will be overwritten with each WordPress update. Instead, you can achieve the same effect by using a child theme and custom functions. This way, your modifications remain intact across updates.

I tried a few different things but I was able to get it working using this technique: ( I am sure there are other solutions )

1. Find your comments.php file in your theme (child theme preferably)
2. Replace this: (or something similar, it is possible that themes can be slightly different depending.

```
wp_list_comments(
            [
                'style'       => 'ol',
                'short_ping'  => true,
                'avatar_size' => 42,
            ]
        );
```

With this:

```
        // Start output buffering
        ob_start();

        // Output comments
        wp_list_comments([
            'style'       => 'ol',
            'short_ping'  => true,
            'avatar_size' => 42,
        ]);

        // Capture the output
        $comments_list = ob_get_clean();
        // Regular expression to match date/time links and modify the hyperlink
        $pattern = '/<a .*?href="(.*?#comment-\d+)".*?>(.*?)<\/a>/i';
        $comments_list = preg_replace($pattern, '<a href="$1" rel="nofollow">$2</a>', $comments_list);
        // Output the modified list
        echo $comments_list;
```

Comment: Thanks big person, but this code didn't work, do I need to edit something?

Comment: Not sure, but calling me "big person" seems condescending. I would recommend not speaking to people like that on this board and in general. It will make people not want to help you.

Comment: I was able to get it working by implementing the above changes.
Please check.

Comment: I apologize for making you upset, Im not very good at English culture
But in our culture this is a good word.
Thank you, I will test it

Comment: Hi, I tested it and it worked successfully, but I don't think it will work on all themes, for example on another of my sites that was using the 2024 theme, there was no such replacement! I don't know but maybe there is a better solution so that others can easily use it, or even a guide that more fully explains the same for all situations.
Anyway, my problem is solved, I just wanted to see if it is possible for you to upvote my question? Because I can't do anything